# spark sql udf cast return value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a variable declare like this :

```
val jobnameSeq = Seq( ("42409245", "name12"),("42461545", "name4"),("42409291", "name1"),("42413872", "name3"),("42417044", "name2"))
```

I want to be able to create a function usable in Spark SQL to substitute `42461545` by `name4` in an sql query.
I tried to declare this function:

```
val jobnameDF = jobnameSeq.toDF("jobid","jobname")
sqlContext.udf.register("getJobname", (id: String) => (
     jobnameDF.filter($"jobid" === id).select($"jobname")
    )
)
```

To be use like this in sql:

```
select getjobname(jobid), other, field from table
```

But `jobnameDF.filter($"jobid" === id).select($"jobname")` returns a DF not a string and I can't figure out how to simply convert this value to string as there will be only one result each time.

If a `Seq` is not the object to use in this case, I'm open to suggestion.

**Edit:**
Though the suggested answer works, here's what I did exactly to make this work:

```
#Convert my seq to a hash map
val jobMap = jobnameSeq.toMap
#declare a sql function so I could use it in sparksql (I need to be accessible to people that don't know scala
sqlContext.udf.register("getJobname", (id: String) => (
    jobMap(id)
    )
)
```

Comment: My goal is just to have a function that return the jobname based on the id provided I don't want to replace any value. @RameshMaharjan I tried to add a bit more context there.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan do you realize I have no full knowledge of the spark framework, I would be delighted to learn a better / new way to do things.

Comment: All I am saying is you don't need spark for your requirement . is your data big ? and your requirement suggests that it would faster and efficient to do it in hashmap

Comment: The sequence is indeed small So not integrated to hdfs. The table on which i need to subsitute the value several time is big indeed.

Comment: then update the question with the substitute part as well. You will certainly get answer

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I really don't understand what you mean does my example isn't speaking for itself ?

Comment: so you want to get the jobid when you provide a stirng? is that it?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I want to extract the name from the id and substitute the id in my request by the name to make it more readable. My `Seq` is small but my table is more than 20Gb

Comment: I have tried to answer using both ways. I hope its helpful to proceed further

Comment: why not just joining the two dataframes? In your case you can do a broadcast-join which isn't causing a shuffle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand from your question, you should be creating a `Map` from your sequence and get the `jobId` directly as

```
val simpleMap = jobnameSeq.toMap

println(simpleMap("42461545"))
```

which should give you `name4`

Now if you want to test with `dataframe`, you can do the following

```
val jobnameDF = jobnameSeq.toDF("jobid","jobname")

val jobName = jobnameDF.filter($"jobid" === "42461545").select("jobname").first().getAs[String]("jobname")

println(jobName)
```

which should print `name4`

Comment: great to hear that @Kiwy :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in many ways:

```
val jobnameSeq = Seq( ("42409245", "name12"),("42461545", "name4"),
                      ("42409291", "name1"),("42413872", "name3"),("42417044", "name2"))
val jobIdDF = Seq( "42409245",("42409291"),("42409231")).toDF("jobID")
jobIdDF.createOrReplaceTempView("JobView")
```

Just use plain scala's `toMap` function on the Jobname Sequence.

```
sqlContext.udf.register("jobNamelookUp", (jobID: String) =>  
                                            jobnameSeq.toMap.getOrElse(jobID,"null"))
```

//OR

If the input is an RDD then use `collectAsMap` using spark.

```
val jobnameMap = sc.parallelize(jobnameSeq).collectAsMap
sqlContext.udf.register("lookupJobName",(jobID:String) => 
                                            jobnameMap.getOrElse(jobID,"null"))
```

//OR

If this lookup is going happen on a cluster then you can `broadcast` it.

```
val jobnameMapBC = sc.broadcast(jobnameMap)
sqlContext.udf.register("lookupJobNameBC",(jobID:String) => 
                                                jobnameMapBC.value.getOrElse(jobID,"null")) 

spark.sql("select jobID,jobNamelookUp(jobID) as jobNameUsingMap,
                        lookupJobNameBC(jobID) as jobNameUsingBC,
                        lookupJobName(jobID) as jobNameUsingRDDMap 
         from JobView")
    .show()

+--------+---------------+--------------+------------------+
|   jobID|jobNameUsingMap|jobNameUsingBC|jobNameUsingRDDMap|
+--------+---------------+--------------+------------------+
|42409245|         name12|        name12|            name12|
|42409291|          name1|         name1|             name1|
|42409231|           null|          null|              null|
+--------+---------------+--------------+------------------+
```

As suggested by `Raphael`, using `broadcast-join`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val jobnameSeqDF = jobnameSeq.toDF("jobID","name")
jobIdDF.join(broadcast(jobnameSeqDF), Seq("jobID"),"leftouter").show(false)

+--------+------+
|jobID   |name  |
+--------+------+
|42409245|name12|
|42409291|name1 |
|42409231|null  |
+--------+------+
```

Comment: another way would be to convert `jobnameSeq` to a Dataframe and simply join it on `table` (using a broadcast-join)

Comment: Added it Raphael. Thanks